# Maximization of a function I came up while studying

Tags: optimization

So in a problem I am trying to solve, after calculations I came up with the following function:

\begin{equation*}
f(\overline{y},\theta)=\frac{e^{n\,min\{\overline{y},\theta)}-1}{n\theta}
\end{equation*}

where $\overline{y}$ a vector of dimension $n$. Is there a way to pick $\theta$ to maximize this function ($\theta$ is a function of the vector $\overline{y})$. Min messes with the derivative so I can't come up with something. Everything is considered to be positive, including $\theta$ and the components of the vector. Thanks!

Comment: What does $\min(\bar y,\theta)$ mean when $\bar y$ is a vector?

Comment: I mean min of all components of the vector and $\theta$, i.e. mean between $n+1$ variables.

Comment: Could you define how $\theta $ depends on $\bar{y}$?

Comment: It can be any function of the components of the vector